# Custom Link Block with own background color

Tags: block-editor, navigation, full-site-editing

`WP-Theme: Twenty Twenty-Three`
with child theme for modifications.

i would like to build a navigation that looks like this:
[image]
for this i used the [Navigation-block](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/navigation-block/) with [Custom Link Blocks](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/custom-link-block/)
and with the help of some additional css i got this fare:
[image]

my Additional CSS (added via the *Editor* - *Styles* `ADDITIONAL CSS`

```css
/* site navigation */
.wp-block-navigation .wp-block-navigation-item {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.wp-block-navigation .wp-block-navigation-item__content {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.wp-block-navigation-item__label s {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

(the small second line in the *buttons* is currently done via a hacked use of the Strikethrough element inline style..)

currently the [Navigation-block](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/navigation-block/) supports a background color.
and the [Custom Link Block](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/custom-link-block/#block-settings) does not.

as the user wants to change the order / count &  colors some-times i would like to make this editable in the ui.

what is the easiest way to add the *normal block background-color setting* option to the Custom-Link Block?

i have read that it is possible in custom blocks to add these via the [`block supports`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-supports-in-static-blocks/)
would it be the easiest way to extend teh Custom-Link Block (=create a new block with this additional feature) ?

anyone other ideas /  easier ways to archive my goal..?

one additional tricky part is the line-height / positioning with the second lines....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this by using the Columns Block.
this was the fastes and easiest way to implement this.
its not perfect as the semantically correct way would be the nav element...